# How can I setup a data quality ruleset that runs on a catalog table created by a crawler in one terraform config?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-glue, terraform-provider-aws

I have to use an AWS Glue Crawler to create and populate a Glue Catalog Table by crawling an AWS RDS MariaDB database.
Once it is created, I want to add AWS Glue Data Quality Rulesets to that new table.
I use Terraform to build the infrastructure.
How can I set this up so in one update, both the crawler and the data quality ruleset get created and are ready to use?

Here's what I have so far (in a module):

```
variable "glue_connection_name" {
  type = string
  description = "Name of the Glue Connection to use."
}

variable "crawler_iam_role_arn" {
  type = string
  description = "ARN of the IAM role to use for the table Crawlers."
}

variable "database_name" {
  type = string
  description = "Name of the Glue Catalog Database to use."
}

variable "table_name" {
  type    = string
  description = "The name of the table to check as in the RDS database."
}

variable "ruleset" {
  type = list(string)
  description = "The rules to check. Quotes must be escaped: `\\\"`"
}

variable "qa_crawlers_prefix" {
  default     = "qa_"
  type        = string
  description = "The prefix QA Glue Crawlers shall set before the automatically generated Glue Catalog table name."
}

resource "aws_glue_crawler" "qa_table_crawler" {
  database_name = var.database_name
  name          = "qa_${var.database_name}-${var.table_name}"
  role          = var.crawler_iam_role_arn
  description   = "Loads the ${var.database_name}.${var.table_name} table into the Glue Catalog."
  table_prefix  = var.qa_crawlers_prefix

  jdbc_target {
    connection_name = var.glue_connection_name
    path            = "${var.database_name}/${var.table_name}"
  }

  tags = {
    Name     = "glue"
    Function = "data processing"
  }
}

resource "aws_glue_data_quality_ruleset" "table_rules" {
  name        = var.table_name
  description = "Checks for the ${var.table_name} table in the ${var.database_name} database"

  ruleset = "Rules = [${join(",", var.ruleset)}]"

  target_table {
    database_name = var.database_name
    table_name    = "${var.qa_crawlers_prefix}${var.database_name}_${var.table_name}"  # This is the name of the table as it will be created by the Glue Crawler
  }

  tags = {
    Name     = "glue-qa-${var.table_name}"
    Function = "data processing"
  }
  depends_on = [aws_glue_crawler.qa_table_crawler]
}
```

I have tried using both the resource and data source `aws_glue_catalog_table`, but the resource means that the Crawler will create a table of the same name with a randomized suffix, making the data quality ruleset config useless, and the data source throws an error during `terraform plan` because the resource does not exist yet.

Setting the name as above makes `terraform plan` work, but `terraform apply` fails because the table is not found.

I have also tried to just leave the `target_table` argument out of the `aws_glue_data_quality_ruleset` resource setup, but I don't know where the ruleset ends up on the console then, making it kinda useless.

Comment: You could use the `terraform apply -target` to create the crawler first, followed by regular `terraform apply` but I'm not sure if that is what you want. The other thing to try maybe is `table_name    = "${aws_glue_crawler.qa_table_crawler.table_prefix}${var.database_name}_${var.table_name}"` which will create an implicit dependency between the crawler and the target table.

Comment: @MarkoE I like your idea of the implicit dependency and will incorporate this. Unfortunately, that does not solve the issue that I still need the crawler to actually run and create the table before I can apply the ruleset in a new run...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing, which seems to work fine, at least when first setting up the crawler and ruleset.

I use `null_resource`s to first create a table for the data quality ruleset and then destroy it once the ruleset for the table is created.
Once the Terraform plan is applied, I go on the AWS Console and run the newly created Crawler.
It once again creates the table to which I created the data quality ruleset.
Once the Crawler is done, the ruleset appears in the newly created and filled table.

Here's the code I used:

```
variable "glue_data_quality_iam_role_arn" {
  type        = string
  description = "ARN of the IAM role to use for Glue Data Quality runs."
}

variable "database_name" {
  description = "Name of the Glue Catalog Database to use."
  type        = string
}

variable "table_name" {
  description = "The name of the table to check as in the RDS database."
  type        = string
}

variable "ruleset" {
  description = "The rules to check. Quotes must be escaped: `\\\"`"
  type        = list(string)
}

variable "qa_crawlers_prefix" {
  description = "The prefix QA Glue Crawlers shall set before the automatically generated Glue Catalog table name."
  type        = string
  default     = "qa_"
}

locals {
  crawler_table_name = "${aws_glue_crawler.jdbc_qa.table_prefix}${var.database_name}_${var.table_name}"
}

resource "aws_glue_crawler" "jdbc_qa" {
  database_name = var.database_name
  name          = "qa_${var.database_name}-${var.table_name}"
  role          = var.glue_data_quality_iam_role_arn
  table_prefix  = var.qa_crawlers_prefix

  jdbc_target {
    connection_name = var.glue_connection_name
    path            = "${var.database_name}/${var.table_name}"
  }

  tags = {
    Name     = "${var.database_name}.${var.table_name} Crawler"
    Function = "data processing"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "create_table" {
  triggers = {
    crawler_prefix = aws_glue_crawler.jdbc_qa.table_prefix
    crawler_target = aws_glue_crawler.jdbc_qa.jdbc_target[0].path
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws glue create-table --database-name ${var.database_name} --table-input '{\"Name\": \"${local.crawler_table_name}\"}'"
  }
}

resource "aws_glue_data_quality_ruleset" "qa_table" {
  name        = "qa_${var.table_name}"

  ruleset = "Rules = [\n\t${join(",\n\t", var.ruleset)}\n]" # newlines and tabs for readability in the AWS Console

  target_table {
    database_name = var.database_name
    table_name    = local.crawler_table_name
  }
  depends_on = [null_resource.create_table]
}

resource "null_resource" "delete_table" {
  triggers = {
    crawler_prefix = aws_glue_crawler.jdbc_qa.table_prefix
    crawler_target = aws_glue_crawler.jdbc_qa.jdbc_target[0].path
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws glue delete-table --database-name ${var.database_name} --name ${local.crawler_table_name}"
  }
  depends_on = [aws_glue_data_quality_ruleset.qa_table]
}
```

Note the name of the table has to be specifically what the Glue Crawler will create, which is not documented by AWS.
I just tried what happens and use a consistent naming schema.